# SCSS "If" condition with commas. How does it work?

Tags: sass

I found this is in code. As I understand `$should-use-modal` should be ether `false` or `true` at the end.

```
$should-use-modal: if(global-variable-exists(use-modal), $use-modal, false) !default;
```

There are 3 parts:

1. `global-variable-exists(use-modal)` - checks if variable `use-modal` exists
2. `$use-modal` is ether `false` or `true` somewhere else in the code.
3. and we have just `false`.

Whats the logic here? If the result will be `true`, `true`, `false` what the outcome will be? or other combination. I dont get it

Answer (score 5):

If condition (first argument) is met then use the second argument, if not the third.

For example:

```
if(true, blue, red) // Outputs "blue"
if(false, blue, red) // Outputs "red"
```

> The built-in if() function allows you to branch on a condition and returns only one of two possible outcomes. It can be used in any script context. The if function only evaluates the argument corresponding to the one that it will return -- this allows you to refer to variables that may not be defined or to have calculations that would otherwise cause an error (E.g. divide by zero).

In your case:

```
$should-use-modal: if(global-variable-exists(use-modal), $use-modal, false) !default;

@if $should-use-modal {
  .modal {
    color: red;
  }
}
```

will not have any css output, because the `$should-use-modal` variable is not defined so `$should-use-modal` is false (assigned as the third if function argument). But if you define the variable:

```
$use-modal: something;
$should-use-modal: if(global-variable-exists(use-modal), $use-modal, false) !default;

@if $should-use-modal {
  .modal {
    color: red;
  }
}
```

will output the following `css` cause the variable is defined.

```
.modal {
  color: red;
}
```

Hope it helps.

More about sass conditionals [here](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#if).